# slideshow jumping from slide 2 to 5 js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Im working with this slide show that i found online, the slideshow is working fine it has some indicator buttons(those buttons that show in what picture you are) also has some arrows that allow you to move to the next photo or to go back. this slide show is using boostrap. Thanks to newman now the play/pause is included, but for some reason it jumps from slide 2 to slide 5, how can fix this :/

HTML code:

```
<div id="slideshow">    
  <div id="s1" class="slide row active"> 
     <img src="images/slide1.png"  alt="" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%; height:auto;"/> 
   </div>

   <div id="s2" class="slide row"> 
     <img src="images/slide2.png" alt="" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%; height:auto;"/> 
   </div>  

   <div id="s3" class="slide row"> 
     <img src="images/slide3.png" alt="" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%; height:auto;"/>  
   </div>

   <div id="s4" class="slide row"> 
     <img src="images/slide4.png" alt="" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%; height:auto;"/>  
   </div>   

   <div id="s5" class="slide row"> 
     <img src="images/slide5.png" alt="" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%; height:auto;"/>        
   </div>

   <div id="s6" class="slide row"> 
     <img src="images/slide6.png" alt="" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%; height:auto;"/> 
   </div> 
  <div id="controls" class="row">
    <div id="left" class="col-xs-6">
      <a href="javascript: previous();"> 
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> 
      </a>  
    </div>
    <div id="right" class="col-xs-6"> 
      <a href="javascript: next();"> 
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> 
      </a> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="indicators" class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
    <a id="i1" href="#s1" class="active"><span class="hiddenText">Slide 1</span></a> 
     <a id="i2" href="#s2"><span class="hiddenText">Slide 2</span></a> 
     <a id="i3" href="#s3"><span class="hiddenText">Slide 3</span></a> 
     <a id="i4" href="#s4"><span class="hiddenText">Slide 4</span></a> 
     <a id="i5" href="#s5"><span class="hiddenText">Slide 5</span></a>  
     <a id="i6" href="#s6"><span class="hiddenText">Slide 6</span></a>
   </div> 
</div>
```

Js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    initSlideshow();
play()
});

var slideCount, currentSlide;
play()  
function initSlideshow(){
    slideCount = 0;
    //count the slides in slideshow
    $('#slideshow .slide').each(function(){
        slideCount++;
    });
    currentSlide = 1;
    jump(); 
}


    function play() {
  next();
  setInterval(function() { play()}, 1000 );
}
function next(){
    //remove active class from current slide & indicator
    $('#slideshow #s' + currentSlide).removeClass('active');
    $('#slideshow #i' + currentSlide).removeClass('active');

    //increment index
    if(currentSlide == slideCount){
        currentSlide = 1;
    }
    else{
        currentSlide++; 
    }

    //add active class to new current slide & indicator
    $('#slideshow #s' + currentSlide).addClass('active');
    $('#slideshow #i' + currentSlide).addClass('active');


}

function previous(){
    //remove active class from current slide & indicator
    $('#slideshow #s' + currentSlide).removeClass('active');    
    $('#slideshow #i' + currentSlide).removeClass('active');        

    //decrement index
    if(currentSlide == 1){
        currentSlide = slideCount;
    }
    else{
        currentSlide--; 
    }

    //add active class to new slide & indicator
    $('#slideshow #s' + currentSlide).addClass('active');   
    $('#slideshow #i' + currentSlide).addClass('active');


}

function jump(){
$('#indicators a').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
//remove active class from current slide & indicator
$('#slideshow #s' + currentSlide).removeClass('active');    
$('#slideshow #i' + currentSlide).removeClass('active');

//change current slide index
currentSlide = $(this).attr('href').slice(2);

//add active class to new slide & indicator
$('#slideshow #s' + currentSlide).addClass('active');   
$('#slideshow #i' + currentSlide).addClass('active');

});
}
```

Comment: can you show us your slide show page

Comment: @ShapCyber the HTML code is the slideshow page.

Comment: i mean show us the working page

Comment: `<a href="javascript: next();">` hurt my eyes. Please don't do that. First of all it's a button, not link. Second of all: Use event listeners so you don't have to expose global functions.

Comment: thanks @Miszy I will keep that in mind, any idea why the slideshow don't work Properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For play button just create function that will call next() function and set Timer for self.

Similar

```
function play() {
  next();
  setTimeout(5000, function(){play();});
}
```

For pause just stop this timer.

Comment: Thank you, for this piece of code. A question how can I made the slide show start over when it reach the last slide.

Comment: In your code it rotate to begin when going to next from last slide

Comment: yes if I use the indicator buttons/arrows it work it goes from the last slide to first one, but not with play button